# Ubunut 20.04 no wifi adapter found randomly

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

The system drops the wifi adapter. After the start everything works fine. Than randomly the wifi adapter disappears. Sometimes even after reboot no wifi anymore. After a while and many reboots its working again for some time. If I just leave the PC turned on without doing anything, no problems occur. This is stange. System is up2date. Using Asus Zenbook 14 UX480.

nmcli device status
working:

```
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
wlo1          wifi      connected     Tattoine ` 
p2p-dev-wlo1  wifi-p2p  disconnected  -- 
lo            loopback  unmanaged     --
```

broken:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Sudo lspci

`00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)`

lspci- v

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at b431c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Do you have any idea?